# Problems understanding code

Tags: java, android

While I was learning Android app development from courses available on Udacity... for user interface and user input everything was fine and understood able but when it comes to topics like printing of ArrayList and array adapter then its literally hard for me understand all those stuff.For example, i don't understand what happening in codes like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Can anyone tell what is the root cause of not understanding those things so that I can work on that part?

Comment: A root cause could be a lacking background in Java--once you have a strong foundation with it, it'll be clear what a lot of the paradigms are and the [Android API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) will be more understandable.

Comment: I wonder if you have started with the basic videos first, because they will certainly explain what's that all about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand how adapter works. A tutorial like this http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/android-recyclerview-tutorial/ will help you understand how to write your custom adapter (This tutorial is for RecyclerView but the main idea of adapter is the same). After you understanding how adapter works you will notice that `ArrayAdapter` is just a convenient way to create a simple adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The List view Shows the entire data in the list form in the android application. and findviewbyid is used to access the data with the id from xml file of your project.

Comment: But what about those ArrayAdapter??

Comment: You can use this adapter to provide views for an AdapterView, Returns a view for each object in a collection of data objects you provide, and can be used with list-based user interface widgets such as ListView or Spinner.
Or
Visit this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html